# find all files in a directory without specified permissions

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I want to list out all the files and directories in a directory without 777 and 755 permissions
Whats the command using linux Ubuntu command prompt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if Folderpath is the path of folder in which you are interested

`ls -l Folderpath | egrep -v 'drwxrwxrwx|drwxr-xr-x|-rwxr-xr-x|-rwxrwxrwx'`

```
will give result in this format
   total 82796
   -rw-rw-rw-  1 imran imran 40203707 Feb 13 14:32 tmp_13-02.14.log
```

removing files and directories with permission 777 and 755

In case you only want the names of files and folders

```
ls -l Folderpath | egrep -v 'drwxrwxrwx|drwxr-xr-x|-rwxr-xr-x|-rwxrwxrwx' |rev|  cut -d ' ' -f 1| rev| tail -n +2
```

```
Output will be
tmp_13-02.14.log
.
.
```

Comment: canc i get filenames ?

Comment: you mean only the filenames? like instead of "-rw-rw-rw-  1 imran imran 40203707 Feb 13 14:32 tmp_13-02.14.log" only tmp_13-02.14.log?

Comment: I have edited my answer to provide only file and directory names